# how to expand and collapse a UIView in ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I've create a pop up in a `viewController` in my pop up there is a `scrollview` and I have some views in it on a `button click`. I want to collapse a view which contains some views itself and on another `button click`. I want to expand the view. I've tried the code bellow the achieve it, but instead of collapse the view and want hide other view.

for collapse I've used below code :

```
        var newFrame : CGRect = view.frame
        newFrame.size.height = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations:{
            self.issueBox.frame = newFrame;
            self.issueBox.isHidden = true

        },completion : nil)
```

for expand :

```
            var newFrame : CGRect = view.frame
        newFrame.size.height = 232

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations:{
            self.issueBox.frame = newFrame;
            self.issueBox.isHidden = false

        },completion : nil)
```

also in my storyboard I've set my constraints for all views. including the one I want to collapse.

so how can I collapse and expand a view?
 this is my view in my viewController :
[image: red box is the one I want to collapse]

I want to collapse red box on clicking "collapse/extend" button, and then "ok" button, comes bellow "collapse/expand" button!

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot or some images?

Comment: @EmreÖnder I've added a screenshot!

Answer (score 1):

Animate the height constraint of the view you want to collapse (toggle between 0 and calculated height of all subviews). Make sure its subviews don't have top|height|bottom constraint as that will result in layout issues - add top & height or bottom & height constraints to the subviews instead. Make sure the view you are animating has `Clip to Bounds` set to `true`. Avoid animating frame when you have constraints. Hope that helps!

Comment: Your answer is confusing -- You say don't add top/bottom/height constraint to the subviews, but the next sentence you say to add them to the subviews? Can you clarify which view we should be adding constraints to?

Comment: Hi @Mocha, I said add top & height OR bottom & height constraints to the subviews, which allows the subviews content to not shrink down and hide smoothly while the superview is collapsing